# Agregar datos a una variable Session ya creada

Tags: c#

quería saber si es posible concatenar un array a una variable de session que ya tiene un array en él:

```
private string GetParametros(string valores)
{
                try
                {
                    string[] datos;
                   
                    if (Session["parametros"] == null)
                    {
                        datos = valores.Split(';');

                        Session["parametros"] = datos;
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        datos = valores.Split(';');

                        Session["parametros"] = Session["parametros"] + datos;

                    }

                }
}
```

En caso de que session["parametros"] sea null me la crea con el string que recibe la función, transformando el string en array, y luego cuando pase denuevo por la función quiero agregar los nuevos valores que le lleguen a Session["parametros"].

Obviamente estoy haciendo algo mal porque   `Session["parametros"] = Session["parametros"] + datos;` me tira error.

Alguien sabe cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Puedes hacer lo siguiente:**

1. Separa los valores de tu sesión en un arreglo de `string` en tu caso.
2. Concatena los valores de parámetros con los valores nuevos usando `Concat()` de la librería `using System.Linq;` que puedes importar y al final se le aplica un `ToArray()` para guardarlos como tipo array.

**Con esto tendrías lo siguiente:**

```
private string GetParametros(string valores)
{
    try
    {
        string[] datos;

        if (Session["parametros"] == null)
        {
            datos = valores.Split(';');
            Session["parametros"] = datos;
        }
        else
        {
            datos = valores.Split(';');
            string[] parametros = Session["parametros"] + datos;
            Session["parametros"] = parametros.Concat(datos).ToArray();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Espero esto te ayude con tu problema.